# Override interface's function callback arguments

Tags: go

I am using a package that has a `Router` interface, and I have created my own app-specific `Router` interface that wraps the third party package.

Everything is working well, however one of the methods is throwing a compilation error:

> controllers/auth.go:52:17: cannot use func literal (type func(router.Router)) as type func(chi.Router) in argument to c.router.Group

This is the interface of the third party package (chi):

```
type Router interface {
    // ...

    // Group adds a new inline-Router along the current routing
    // path, with a fresh middleware stack for the inline-Router.
    Group(fn func(r Router)) Router

    // ...
}
```

This is my wrapper interface:

```
type Router interface {
    chi.Router

    // Custom methods...
}
```

My usage of the `Group` function is like so:

```
type AuthController struct {
    router router.Router
    // ...
}

func (c *AuthController) SetRoutes() {
    c.router.Group(func(r router.Router) {
        r.Use(middleware.Anyone)

        r.Post("/auth/register", c.Register)
        r.Post("/auth/login", c.Authenticate)
        r.Post("/auth/token/refresh", c.RefreshToken)
    })

    c.router.Group(func(r router.Router) {
        r.Use(middleware.Authorized)

        r.Get("/auth/ping", c.Ping)
        r.Post("/auth/logout", c.Logout)
    })
}
```

Why is it screaming at my function callbacks argument type? My wrapper `router.Router` implements the `chi.Router` interface, so it should work fine shouldn't it? Am I misunderstanding how Go works here?

Comment: at first look `chi.Router` type is not the same as `router.Router`

Comment: @YandryPozo Yes, but they are both interfaces. Shouldn't the compiler see them as the same thing so long as the interfaces comply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see how this can be confusing so I will try to break it down. You have this method:

```
Group(fn func(r Router)) Router
```

This method takes a function as a parameter. That function must have a specific signature:

```
func(r Router)
```

That is, it takes a single argument of type `chi.Router` and has no return values. However, when you call it:

```
c.router.Group(func(r router.Router) { /***/ }
```

You're passing in a function of the wrong signature; your function signature is:

```
func(r router.Router)
```

That's not the signature required by the method you're calling, so it won't compile. It doesn't matter if `router.Router` implements `chi.Router`; the parameter (a `func(router.Router)`) passed is not of the expected type (a `func(chi.Router)`).

This may seem silly at first - after all, any `router.Router` must implement `chi.Router`. But, think about it: that method, `Group`, is expecting to receive a function, to which it can pass *any* `chi.Router`. That means it can pass a `chi.Router` which *does not implement* `router.Router`. If it were to accept your function, it would break type safety, and what in Go is meant to be a compile-time error (the error you're getting, in fact) would become a run-time error. Basically, by passing a function with a different (and more strict) argument type, you're expecting a guarantee which that method never offered.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. I missed that there's a difference between a function signature, and the actual value you're passing in when invoking that function. Makes perfect sense now. I guess I'll have to create my own `Group` method that wraps the libs `Group` method and does a type assertion internally or something.

Answer (score 2):

The parameter types aren't the same, so the function type doesn't match what's expected, even though your interface includes the interface from the other package (the type has to match exactly). You need to have your functions take a `chi.router` and then use a type assertion, i.e., `myRouter := r.(Router)`, to convert to your type.

Comment: But this doesn't make any sense... all throughout the standard library there are examples of functions taking interface type arguments (like a `Reader` and `Writer`) and anything that implements that interface is allowed in, so why is this any different?

Comment: You're conflating variables and signatures. You can pass anything that implements that interface as an argument, yes, but *the method signature must be **identical** to what's in the interface to satisfy the interface.* The same goes for function types - the signatures must be *identical*.

Comment: I see.. it all makes sense now.